# Facing problem in retrieving a specific key name from a JSON api

Tags: javascript, json, key

I have an API with the follwing JSON signature:

```
[{
   "id": 3,
   "impact": 7,
   "probability": 0.7,
   "title": "Risk 3"
}]
```

Now I have lets say 3 similar objects in this format which actually demonstrates different risk names or numbers of a company. Now I need to find which risk number has the highest impact or probability. Also which risk has the highest RPZ,

```
 RPZ = impact * probability
```

I have managed to find the highest values of any of the properties in the json. But I have tried lot of ways to figure out the title or risk name associated to it. This is my target which I am not able to do. For example my goal is to get the highest value, lets say the impact from the above example, which is 7 and also to print out its risk name which is the title here. I was able to get the highest values but failing to print out its corresponding risk name or title.

a liitle snippet....

```
var con = JSON.parse(body);

var highImpact = Math.max.apply(Math, con.map(i => i.impact));
```

now from the above highImpact which is 7, now I need to pull out the corresponding risk name which would be......Risk 3. This is where I am struggling.

I have checked a lot of similar questions asked by other developers in this community and also several web pages and blogs found in the internet. But nothing got me a solution till now.

If some one of you can help me it would be really grateful

v

```
ar Request = require('request');


Request.get("https://webdevbootcamp-jay-jayantamgr.c9users.io/api/risks", (error, response, body) => {
    if(error)
    {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    var con = JSON.parse(body);

    var highImpact = Math.max.apply(Math, con.map(i => i.impact));


    var highProb = Math.max.apply(Math, con.map(p => p.propability));



    let dictRPZ = [];
    function addRPZ(RiskName, RPZ){
        dictRPZ.push({RiskName, RPZ});
    }

    con.forEach(function(item){
        var RPZ = item.impact * item.propability;
        addRPZ(item.title, RPZ);
    });

});
```

Expected result is to make a Dashboard and show the risk with highest impact, highest RPZ, live table of the risks and a moving average chart

Comment: To put this very simply: you have an array of objects like those you desribe, and you want to get the name of the object that has the highest value of impact multiplied with probability?

Comment: Seems like a simple use case for `find()`

Comment: Or sort the array by impact descending, and then the first object is your highest impact and you can grab whatever you want off it

Comment: Hi Roi, yes, you got it right, thanks for your response, but however I go the solution, also thanks to Taplar for the effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this with sorting in descending order and selecting the first element of sorted array.

```js
let arr = [
  { "id": 3, "impact": 7, "probability": 0.7, "title": "Risk 3" },
  { "id": 4, "impact": 8, "probability": 0.8, "title": "Risk 4" }
]

let highestImpact = arr.sort((a,b)=>b.impact-a.impact)[0].title;

console.log(highestImpact)
```

For highest `RPZ` you can do it like this

```js
let arr = [
      { "id": 3, "impact": 7, "probability": 0.7, "title": "Risk 3" },
      { "id": 4, "impact": 8, "probability": 0.8, "title": "Risk 4" },
      { "id": 5, "impact": 10, "probability": 0.8, "title": "Risk 5" }
]

let highestRpz = arr.map(e=> {
 e.rpz= e.impact * e.probability
 return e;
 }).sort((a,b)=>b.rpz-a.rpz)[0].title

    console.log(highestRpz)
```

Comment: Hi, Code Maniac, thanks for the answer, it works now exactly I wanted it, thanks a lot

Comment: @Jay always happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the max value by applying the formula in a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) loop always returning the max (by whatever criterion you want). This is more efficient than sorting the entire array since you only need a single pass and you don't create a new array just to throw it away.. It will return the object from the array meeting the criteria you set:

```js
let arr = [
    { "id": 3, "impact": 7, "probability": 0.7, "title": "Risk 3" },
    { "id": 4, "impact": 4, "probability": 0.72, "title": "Risk 4" },
    { "id": 5, "impact": 1, "probability": 0.6, "title": "Risk 5" },    
    { "id": 6, "impact": 8, "probability": 0.91, "title": "Risk 6" }
]

// max impact * probability
let max = arr.reduce((max, current) => 
    current.impact * current.probability > max.impact * max.probability
    ? current
    : max
)
console.log(max)
```

For a single value it's the same idea, but simpler:

```js
let arr = [
    { "id": 3, "impact": 7, "probability": 0.7, "title": "Risk 3" },
    { "id": 4, "impact": 4, "probability": 0.72, "title": "Risk 4" },
    { "id": 5, "impact": 9, "probability": 0.1, "title": "Risk 5" },    
    { "id": 6, "impact": 8, "probability": 0.91, "title": "Risk 6" }
]

// max impact
let max = arr.reduce((max, current) => 
    current.impact > max.impact 
    ? current
    : max
)
console.log(max)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example:

```
  function findHighest(arr){
    var highest = arr[0];

    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let current = arr[i]
        let rpz = current.impact * current.probability;
        if(rpz > (highest.impact * highest.probability)) {
            highest = current
        }
    }
    return highest.title
}
```